# How to persist image on Firebase Storage with Glide v4 over the device restart?

Tags: android, android-glide

as the title, I am using Glide v4 to load image from Firebase Storage. I config   Glide to cache the image already loaded like this :

```
 Glide.with(myApplicationContext).load(url).thumbnail(0.5f).dontAnimate()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                .into(view);
```

but the problem is that when the device restart, all cache is clear and if the app does not have connection to the internet, there is no image will be shown. **How can I persist Glide cache over the device restart ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Your code and when turn off wifi/internet and restart (Xiaomi Mi A2) image is persisted.

My code in Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val url =
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513618827672-0d7c5ad591b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9"
        Glide.with(applicationContext).load(url).thumbnail(0.5f).dontAnimate()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
            .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try again, because i am using Huawei nova 3i to test that